# Laravel 4: redirect users after login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have page that not allowed for guests, so if guest visit it automatically redirect to login page,

the question is, Is there any simple way (included in Laravel) to return him back to first page after logged in successfully?

I know I can use with() in first redirection:

```
Redirect::action('UserController@login')->with('url', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
or
Redirect::action('UserController@login')->withUrl($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

then store and use it in login page,

but is there something already built in Laravel,

thanks,

Comment: Might not be the problem, but you misstyped `wiht`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, when your user first enters your site, Laravel stores the entry page in the Session, so, as soon as a login is successful, you can:

```
return Redirect::intended();
```

Note that this probably only work if keep using

```
return Redirect::guest('login');
```

In your filtered Route. This is the original Laravel code (filters.php) that provides this:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');
});
```

You can also set a default page (just in case the intended is not available at the moment) using:

```
return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
```

And you can change the original intended by setting a new one using `Session`:

```
Session::put('url.intended', $newUrl);
```

Comment: I just could find code for that in Redirect::guest(), but Laravel does a lot of magic, so it must be storing it somehow... Your filter doesn't use Redirect::guest() anymore, you removed it?

Comment: I think intended() use property in Redirect class

Comment: It does get(), but only Redirect::guest() does a put().

Answer (score 0):

As Antonio's answer states, you can use:

```
return Redirect::intended();
```

and it will redirect the user to the page the originally intended to go to, but you can pass an optional 'defualt' paramter so if they login at the login page with no intended location, it will redirect them to the default.

```
i.e. return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
```